# Item Position changes when used inside carousel

Tags: html, angularjs, css

I have a fixed `button` positioned to the bottom of the first page slider, where I use css `Translate3d` to change position in swipe up and down, the problem that when I first load the page the fixed button appears in a wrong position, but when I start swipe to change the page the button change it's position, how to fix this ?

GIF :

[image]

I've reproduced the issue in this [**JSBIN**](https://jsbin.com/quxemuk/edit?css,js,output).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `transform: translate3d(0px, 0px, 0px);` to your css class `div.carouselWrap` and you will be fine. Take a look at this [working JSBIN](https://jsbin.com/hipilamubi/1/edit?css,js,output).

```
div.carouselWrap {
    width: 1036px;
    background: white;
    height: 100%;
    color: white;
    font-family: "Gill Sans / Gill Sans MT", sans-serif;
    font-size: 3em;
    line-height: 568px;
    text-align: center;
    transform: translate3d(0px, 0px, 0px);
}
```